Network Design: Daisy Chaining vs One Centralized Switch
I am curious as to what the "standard" is when it comes to designing a network with the given constraints:\

cable runs would be more than what cat5e/6 would allow without a repeater\
one property, multiple buildings with a switch in different buildings, 6 total
one firewall, with up to 7 interfaces

I believe it makes sense to use a layer 3 switch or router and have each layer 2 switch running to it, then from the layer 3 switch into the firewall.
It also makes sense to daisy chain each switch together as an uplink then also use one interface on the firewall.
Obvious Constraints:\

if you use a l3 switch, you have a single point of failure
if you daisy chain, you have failures that could be as bad depending on the l2 switch that fails\

Are any of these standard practice? If not, what is the standard/best way to do it?

Trees, not lines or loops. A distribution switch can be a blade chassis with dual supervisors, or it could be a stack of switches (redundant supervisors). Use fiber to connect the access switches to the distribution switch(es).

so you're saying implement the access/distribution/core idea? This is what I believe to be a tree topology, how would this work given the descirbed situation?

Simply run fiber from the distribution to the access switches. The distribution switch can be a collapsed core running as your LAN router (better than using the firewall for that).

Do these Q&A answer your question? https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/83498/switches-in-chain-topology-for-40-devices https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/76347/connecting-switches-in-daisy-chain-ring https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/83766/how-do-layer-2-switches-route-based-on-mac-when-daisy-chained

Network Design 101. There are 3 general concepts, but no "standard". They all have their own set of pluses and minuses. There are too many questions left unanswered (I suspect, unasked) to point to one over the others.

Tree
Hub and Spoke ("star")
Ring

A "chain" is just an open ring. And "one central switch" could either be a tree, or a "star". Either construct is easily broken by a single link or switch failing - the star having one massive point of failure at the center. Spanning-tree limits the size of a network to 7 hops; doing everything at layer-3 trades STP for a routing protocol.
No matter how you build your network, plan ahead for device(s) and link(s) failing... because at some point they will. (lightning, backhoes, squirrels,... stuff happens.)

A single switch is a star, a "multi-star" of several switches is a tree.

For the purposes of a topology (diagram), only the other switches (and maybe routers) count. Thus, a single switch is a point - i.e. none of these things. Noah is clearly talking about more than one switch in more than one location.

It would cost more to deploy a tree topology since it would be used for redundancy, you would want multiple L3 switches that connect to each switch in case of a failure. Are budget costs valid reasons to not deploy this kind of topology; would it hold up in a meeting?
